# How to add my application to visual Studio as a plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have developed a desktop application for generating a file. Now I want to add that application to visual-studio 2005. How can I do it ? [image: example image]

As an example when I click Edit navigator(according to image) I want to load my application.

Comment: Is your application an actual VS plugin? Or do you just want to be able to open it from VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add your application to the Tools menu in VS by heading to Tools > External Tools and then adding the command to open your program. Your application will then appear in the Tools menu and you can click on it to open it. I'm basing this answer off VS 2010 as I do not have 2005 handy but it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio extensibility is what you want to learn about.  You could start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb187341(v=VS.80).aspx.

Visual Studio Extensibility has evolved over the years, features and techniques that work in later versions of Visual Studio may not be available in earlier versions like Visual Studio 2005.  Anything using the Managed Extensibility Framework for example will only work in Visual Studio 2010.